# using enums in place of String

Tags: java, string, enums

I am executing a java code for conversion of number to words(e.g. 999--> nine hundred ninety nine). I have used two String for defining words.

```
private static final String[] tensWords ={ "", " ten", " twenty", " thirty"}
public enum tenWords{ten, twenty, thirty}
```

When I am using **enum** I am not able to put **blank" "** as in String array. So its causing wrong output.  please suggest how to solve  this.  below is code where I am  using enum to access values.

```
if (number % 100 < 20)
{
    soFar = tensWords.values()[number % 100].toString();
    number /= 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use enums and assign values:

```
public enum TenWords{
     ZERO(""), TEN("ten"), TWENTY("twenty"), THIRTY("thirty");

     private final String value;
     private TenWords(String value) {
       this.value = value;
     }
     public String getValue() {
       return value;
     }
}
```

and access it like:

```
System.out.println(TEN.getValue());
System.out.println(ZERO.getValue());
```

Comment: you should make your constructor also **private** and your field **final** I think

Comment: Thanks, Andreas_D I did as you suggested and it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can use enum parameters to store whatever you want in enum value:

```
enum TensWords {
    NONE(""),
    TEN("Ten"),
    TWENTY("Twenty");
    ///...

    private final String text;

    TensWords(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Also consider moving your code to determine TensWords by number into enum as a static method.

Comment: you should make your constructor also **private** I think

Comment: This is not necessary as far as compiler does not allow you to instantiate enums. This is the same like putting `public` modifier to interface methods - you can do it, but it reads better without them.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement toString() on the enum,in order to have the space you need.